# Combine Loop Query Results into 1

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a loop that queries a SP and returns results in a query, I want to combine that query (however many times the loop runs) into one final query so I can output in my jgrid table. Here is the code:

```
  <cfloop query="query1">
      <cfstoredproc procedure="[Columns]" datasource="#CompanyDB#">
        <cfprocresult name="queryResults">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#query1.ID#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#query1.Role#">
    </cfstoredproc>
  </cfloop>
```

So, here it loops 2 times hence I get 2 queryResults. I want to combine the results into 1 big query so I can then output in jGrid query.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you have not tried anything yet, start by doing a search on [coldfusion combine queries](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcoldfusion%5D+combine+queries) to get a few ideas. That said, running queries within a loop typically is not a great approach and can often be restructured to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

As Leigh mentioned, it's not a great approach and can probably be managed in a much cleaner way, but there's a few ways you could do what you're asking:

Use queryNew() and other related functions to construct your own query object and populate it through each loop.

Use query-of-queries to UNION the results as you go through the loop eg:

```
<cfloop query="query1">
<cfstoredproc procedure="[Columns]" datasource="#CompanyDB#">
    <cfprocresult name="queryResults">
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#query1.ID#">
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#query1.Role#">
</cfstoredproc>
<cfquery name="finalResults" dbtype="query">
    <cfif isDefined('finalResults')>
        ( SELECT * FROM finalResults )
        UNION ALL
    </cfif>
    ( SELECT * FROM queryResults )
</cfquery>
```